# Suppressing/Filtering resource attributes when using respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.

When using [respond_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with) to output JSON/XML/HTML, it dumps all of the attributes by default. What is a good strategy to hide/filter/suppress resource attributes that should not be rendered?

The article [here](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1212245) explains what `respond_with` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options.

You can overwrite the `as_json` method on the model you are working with
http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

You can use a json builder
[jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)
[rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

You could create a serializer
http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

or you could use the `:only` option on `to_json`

```
def index
  @models = Model.all
  respond_with(@models) do |format|
    format.html { render }
    format.json { 
      render json: @models.to_json(
        only: [:some_attribute, :some_other_attribute]
      )
    }
  end
end
```

Unless you are using these constraints in many actions I would recommend the last choice (using `:only` because I believe it to be the simplest but you may feel like the controller isn't the place for this kind of logic.

And there are probably many more ways to do this.

**Edit**:
`respond_with` takes a hash as a second argument to make the above prettier (thanks @ck3g)

```
def index
  @models = Model.all
  respond_with @models, only: [:some_attribute, :some_other_attribute]
end
```

Comment: The `:only` option works with `respons_with` as well. I prefer this solution: `respond_with @user, only: [:id, :email, :phone]`. It looks much cleaner.

Comment: Great. It isn't documented (AFAIK). I will update the answer and start using this. Thanks @ck3g